# extract weigth kg from string php

Tags: php, string

Hello i have this string like this

```
$str = "tea dae 15 abc 7,2 kg abc aa 1 aa"
```

i want to get only kg value like this

```
$str = "7,2kg";
```

i tried this but is not working

```
$result = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
$result = str_replace(',', '.', $result);
$result = strtok($result, "kg");
$result = str_replace('.', ',',(float) filter_var( $result, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ));
```

thank to help

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks work like charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
$str = "tea dae 15 abc 7,2 kg abc aa 1 aa";
$result = "";
if (preg_match('~(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*(kg)\b~', $str, $m)) {
  $result = $m[1] . $m[2];
}
echo $result;
```

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/XSE1J).

The regex is

```
(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*(kg)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SjJnud/2). It will match

- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:,\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a comma and 1 or more digits
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(kg)\b` - `kg` captured in Group 2 as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary).

The final result is concatenation of two groups.